# Cannot read property 'visitExpression' of undefined after copying module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am currently working on an Angular2 project with custom modules to keep the code clean. Everything was fine until I copied this module into another project.

Ever since I've copied the module into another project, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visitExpression' of undefined`.

After hours of googling I found out a couple of possible reasons, which I have all tested (and did not work):

- Double comma's (,,) in the routing
- Empty selectors in components

Here are some other things I tried:

- Look up every import in the module and make sure it is correct.
- Build the typescript files with Gulp (build succeeded without warnings/errors)

I am kind of clue less as to what to try next, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Any misplaced commas in Routes array can cause this

```
const authRoutes: Routes = [,        //<--- This was my issue when I faced it
  {path: 'signup', component:  SignupComponent},
  {path: 'signin', component:  SigninComponent},
]
```

Comment: in my case, error still pops up with all my routes disabled. It's not always the routes causing that error. Since the error is uselessly ambiguous, no way for me to even debug.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there may be a extra comma or different expression in imports.

Answer (score 0):

I got it because of misplacing comma

```
 const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
 ];
```